# make rsync sync to older files

Tags: linux, rsync

I very often use

```
rsync -a  source/ destination/
```

or even

```
rsync -a --delete source/ destination/
```

to make `destination` directory exactly match `source`.

However, if `destination` contains files never than `source`, just the timestamp in my case, rsync leaves them as they are. How can I make rsync to completely sync `destianation` to `source` in any case?

Answer (score 0):

`man rsync` says:

```
-c, --checksum      skip based on checksum, not mod-time & size
```

However, this can have a performance impact.

As far as I can tell, if you also use:

```
-t, --times         preserve modification times
```

the modification timestamps on the destination are updated even if the file isn't copied due to identical checksum.

Comment: Won't adapt timestamp of equal files I guess. It seems rsync just refuses to 'downgrade' files. It is merely an update tool than a sync tool in this way.

Comment: If you also use -t the timestamp is updated as far as I can tell, even if the file isn't copied due to identical checksum.